# Run script on install (vb.net and Python)

Tags: python, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, installation

I am using a visual studios installer to install a couple of applications. I have a Python script that i have exported to an .exe that sets up and creates a database if the application is going to be a server.

Question: How can i make the script run on program install , and stop if there is an error in the script?

Answer (score 2):

- Right click on the solution and select View > Custom Actions.
- Right Click on the Install folder and select Add Custom Action.
- Add File on the file you need to run

Pretty sure that's all there is to it. The .NET Deployment creates a MSI file that allows more complex modifications by MSI tools outside of VS.